# Setear value de un input radio a un input text vacio

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Quiero pasar el value de un input radio seleccionado en un modal, a un input text vacio que tengo en un formulario.

Radio del modal:

```
        <div class="img-user-profile">
            @foreach($files as $image)
                <label class="checkeable">
                    <input type="radio" id="image-profile-radio" name="image-profile" value="{{'images/user-profile/'.$image->getRelativePathname()}}"/>
                    <img src="{{asset('images/user-profile/'.$image->getRelativePathname()) }}">
                </label>
            @endforeach

 <button id="confirm-image-profile" class="btn btn-primary btn-block joinOnlineEventButton">
 Confirm selection
 </button>
```

Lo quiero guardar en este campo del formulario del cual se abre el modal.

```
                <div class="hide">
                    <input type="text" class="input-image-random" name="input-image-random" id="input-image-random" value="">

                </div>
```

He probado con estas dos funciones, pero no logro que se quede guardado en el value del input text:

```
$("#confirm-image-profile").click(function() {
    $("#confirm-image-profile").click(function() {
        $("input[name='image-profile']").change(function(){
            $("#input-image-random").val($("input[name='image-profile']:checked").val());
        });
    });
});

$("#confirm-image-profile").click(function() {
    let imageProfile = $("input[name='image-profile']:checked").val();
    let imagenProfileForm = imageProfile;
    console.log(imagenProfileForm + ' a')
    console.log(imageProfile)
    $('#show-upload-user-photo').modal('hide');

});
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a guardar ese valor ahí?

Comment: quieres pasar el boolean a string?

Comment: Quiero coger el value del radio qye esté cheked y guardarlo en el valye del input text

Comment: ahh ok, no puedes hacerlo por medio de un loop, estas asignando el mismo id y jquery no encuentra el valor, tienes dos opciones o generar un id dinamico o extraer el dato por medio de la clase, si son varias opciones yo mejor te recomiendo un radio buttom, podrias subir una imagen de como tienes el campo por favor?